# Eletron sobrepor outras telas

Tags: node.js

Galera tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida em "Eletron" gostaria de saber se é possível fazer ele sobrepor outro aplicativo quando estiver em background.

Ex. Toda vez que o aplicativo receber um pedido, o aplicativo deveria mostrar imediatamente a tela para o usuário.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow();
mainWindow.show();
```